# ArgumentError creating instance of Time class on Ruby version 1.8.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get the time value using datetime_select from the view, return values obtained are:

```
"scheduletime"=>{"scheduletime(1i)"=>"2014", "scheduletime(2i)"=>"1", "scheduletime(3i)"=>"9", "scheduletime(4i)"=>"10", "scheduletime(5i)"=>"33"}
```

In controller I'm trying to create the instance of Time class using the return values of datetime_select. In following manner.

```
schedule_time = Time.new(params[:scheduletime]["scheduletime(1i)"], params[:scheduletime]["scheduletime(2i)"], params[:scheduletime]["scheduletime(3i)"], params[:scheduletime]["scheduletime(4i)"], params[:scheduletime]["scheduletime(5i)"],0, "+09:00")
```

Trying this I'm getting following error.

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (7 for 0))
```

The version of ruby I'm using is 1.8.6 . Can any one suggest me where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Time.html) seems to point that you can't pass arguments to the `Time.new`  method.

Try this instead (will use your current TimeZone):

```
schedule_time = Time.local(params[:scheduletime]["scheduletime(1i)"], params[:scheduletime]["scheduletime(2i)"], params[:scheduletime]["scheduletime(3i)"], params[:scheduletime]["scheduletime(4i)"], params[:scheduletime]["scheduletime(5i)"],0)

# some variants, using standard TimeZone:
Time.utc(2000,"jan",1,20,15,1)  #=> Sat Jan 01 20:15:01 UTC 2000
Time.gm(2000,"jan",1,20,15,1)   #=> Sat Jan 01 20:15:01 UTC 2000
Time.local(2000,"jan",1,20,15,1)   #=> Sat Jan 01 20:15:01 CST 2000
```

You might want to set the TimeZone to a different one after that.

Comment: Time.local worked for me. However Time.utc dint work.

Answer (score 2):

`Time.new` in Ruby 1.8.6 did not allowed any param. See the [official documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.6/Time.html#method-c-new).

```
a = Time.new      #=> Wed Apr 09 08:56:03 CDT 2003
b = Time.new      #=> Wed Apr 09 08:56:03 CDT 2003
a == b            #=> false
"%.6f" % a.to_f   #=> "1049896563.230740"
"%.6f" % b.to_f   #=> "1049896563.231466"
```

My suggestion is to use [`Time.utc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.6/Time.html#method-c-utc) in order to create a date with given params.

You can rewrite the code using `Hash#valutes_at`

```
Time.utc(*params[:scheduletime].values_at(%w( scheduletime(1i) scheduletime(2i) scheduletime(3i) scheduletime(4i) scheduletime(5i) )))
```

Note that `Time.utc` also accepts an optional time zone (given I see you are passing one).

---

As a side note, you definitely need to upgrade your Ruby version.